# jsFiddle blocks any code containing 'window.location.href = ...'?

Tags: javascript, jsfiddle

I was working on a fairly large prototype in jsFiddle (which I've used many times for a similar purpose), and got an unpleasant shock when I hit the 'Update' button only be sent straight to http://jsfiddle.net with a completely empty code editor.

Luckily hitting 'Back' in the browser was sufficient to recover the lost code.  But I quickly found that my code could not be saved, and that the problem didn't seem to affect any other bit of code on the site.

After a lot of trial and error, I determined that the code could not be saved due to the following benign-looking line:

`window.location.href = "/u/deleteReport?reportId=" + reportId;`

In fact, it appears that it's impossible to save any code (not even the most trivial of examples) on jsFiddle that contains `window.location.href.*=.*;`.  I'm a bit surprised by this fact, and wondering if anyone knows why this limitation exists?  It seems somewhat arbitrary and also entirely ineffective, as things like `window["location"].href = "...";` are still allowed.

Here's an example; the following code can be saved in jsFiddle without any problems:

```
var path = window.location.href;
$("a").click(function(e) {
    window["location"].href = path;  
});
```

...while trying to save this *equivalent* code will dump you straight to the jsfiddle index page:

```
var path = window.location.href;
$("a").click(function(e) {
    window.location.href = path;  
});
```

[Refer this Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jQu3L/6/)

Does anyone know of an explanation for why this happens?

Comment: This is due to spam. We're blocking all code that's abusing our service.

Comment: Might it be more effective/less disruptive to legitimate users to filter against the offending url's/url fragments instead of specific (and commonly used) bits of code?

Comment: Tried this, we're better off with blocking code.

Comment: @OskarKrawczyk Why don't you post that as an answer?